# Expand file system not needed anymore?

Tags: raspbian-buster, filesystem, raspi-config, resize

Expanding the file system on the first boot of a fresh Raspberry Pi OS (buster) - or expanding it at all - has always been under discussion and there is a lot of material out there for how to do it.

But now, with the recent Raspberry Pi lite images, for me it looks like the file system is already expanded to max. When I check my disks with `df -h`, my root partition is `7.x MB` on a 8 MB SD card, and `15.x MB` on a 16 GB SD card. That's already all I need, right?

Is automatic resizing done automatically nowadays?

Comment: First boot expands the root FS to fill the whole SDCard. That's done with /etc/init.d/resize2fs_once which runs on first boot then gets deleted. That's there on RaspiOS Buster Lite.

Comment: *automatic resizing done automatically* - the clue is in the word "automatic" - yes, automatic resizing is done now, before (years ago now) there was no automatic resizing - therefore no automatic resizing was performed

Comment: Why is it still in the menu of raspi-config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is given in the comment of *@Dougie*:

> First boot expands the root FS to fill the whole SDCard. That's done with /etc/init.d/resize2fs_once which runs on first boot then gets deleted. That's there on RaspiOS Buster Lite.

and in the comment of *@JaromandaX*:

> *automatic resizing done automatically* - the clue is in the word "automatic" - yes, automatic resizing is done now, before (years ago now) there was no automatic resizing - therefore no automatic resizing was performed.